How do we test a React component that fetches inside a useEffect using Jest?
I have the following compoent and I need to write a test for that.
How can I mock the fetched data so the state fetchedEmbed could be equal to the mockModel object?
    type OembedResponse = {
      html: string;
      width: number;
      height: number;
    };

const mockModel = {
    "type": "rich",
    "version": "1.0",
    "title": "Überlegen Sie, eine Wärmepumpe einzubauen?",
    "provider_name": "Opinary",
    "provider_url": "https://www.opinary.com/",
    "author_name": "rtl",
    "cache_age": 10800,
    "html": "<div class=\"opinary-widget-embed\" data-poll=\"berlegen-sie-eine-wrmepumpe-einzubauen_r\" data-customer=\"rtl\" data-integration=\"oembed-widget\"></div>\n\t<script async type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"//widgets.opinary.com/embed.js\"></script>",
    "width": 500,
    "height": 500
  }

    export default function Embed({ model }: { readonly model: StorylineEmbedType }) {
      const [fetchedEmbed, setFetchedEmbed] = useState<OembedResponse>();

      useEffect(() => {
        fetch(`apiCall`)
          .then((res) => res.json())
          .then((data) => {
            data.html && setFetchedEmbed(data);
          });
        return () => {
          setFetchedEmbed(undefined);
        };
        // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
      }, []);

      return (
        <div className={styles.root}>
          {fetchedEmbed ? parse(`${fetchedEmbed.html}`) : <div className={styles.loading}></div>}
        </div>
      );
    }


What about testing the rendered output?

Long story short: use jest.spyOn or jest.mock
The first option is like that:
beforeEach(() => {
  jest.spyOn(global, 'fetch').mockResolvedValue(mockModel);

afterAll(() => {
  jest.clearAllMocks()
})

So, basically you mock whole fetch.
But I'd recommend creating api-class to make HTTP request and mock it with jest.mock, because it gives you much more control of what's happening.
